# how do I make javascript work with htm l loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This should be pretty straight forward but i jus can't wrap my head around it an d would appreciate any help.

I have php home page with some JavaScript at the bottom. All this script does is that it calls a function on load of window, and echoes the navigation and this works very well.

The question is that when the nav. is populated, my javascript on the main page cannot interact with it.

```
//Ajax that loads the nav
window.onload = function(){
 function loadContent(where,what) {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { 
  var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); 
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

    xmlhttp.open('GET', what,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};

//the nav function is called directly under it

loadContent('navigator','include/navigation.php');

//after the above is loaded, any javascript written to call an element from the loaded html does not work.
```

};

The navigation.php simply contains some html to be echoed and this also works brilliantly.

```
echo'
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right animate animated fadeInDown">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"  aria-expanded="false">Select Country<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Worldwide</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">UK</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nigeria</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ghana</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kenya</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Calender</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"                 id="loginbutton">Log In</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" id="logout">Log Out</a></li>
```

'

Now my dilemma is now that the above has been loaded. Any JavaScript i write in my window.onload function doesn't work with any of the element in the above. I'ld appeciate any help. Using vanilla js pls so no jquery. Thank you

Comment: That's because the html loaded from your ajax call isn't in the DOM element.. What you need to do is start searching for an element, from its parent, ex: $(body).on('click', '.nav-item', function() {});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making jquery .on function work with AJAX loaded content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416689/making-jquery-on-function-work-with-ajax-loaded-content)

Comment: You coul use a listener. That way it will keep looking for any elements which are added after the page has loaded

Comment: Why can't we keep jQuery out for atleast a js question

Comment: can i get an example in pure js and not jquery please. Thanks

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see many posts recommending `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200`. But after loads of trials, it failed to load the content reliably. Then using firebug i discovered that an OK flag is always present when the content is displayed, so i gave a try with `xhr.statusText === "OK"` and it worked reliably and everytime. Then over to w3 website i discovered that OK flag is given only after content is loaded, just like `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200`. And over at MSDN forum, i checked their method and they too used `xhr.statusText === "OK"`. I don't know why but this is what worked best for me. Here is some more code:

```js
var d=document.getElementById("clicks");
 
var ajaxCall = function() {
    var d=document.getElementById("clicks");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/JSON/text.txt", true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.statusText === "OK") {
        d.innerHTML = xhr.response;
        } else {
        d.innerHTML = "No";
        }
    }


    };

   d.addEventListener("click",ajaxCall,false);
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem here is not loading the content. The content loads just fine but after it does. I cannot use javascript on that section of the code

Comment: The real problem is not about javascript, but how content is loaded. Your php include is served along with js.So your js finds no elements to interact with. Always remember that it is important for html to be present for DOM manipulation. Unless php include converts to html code, any js load before it will not find any DOM content for it. You can try lazy load your js using initial script tag.

Comment: ok, so now that the new element has been created, how do i make javascript interact with it. window.onload doesnt work

Comment: You should apply js through script binded with your ajax rather than page. This will clear priority game played by scripts and browsers. Alternatively, call another ajax after your first ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST", //GET/POST
    url: "handler.php" //URL where you will check everything or give your response
    data: {varName: $variable }
}).done(function(data){
    $("div").append(data); //Puts data in div
});
```

This is how a AJAX request works!!!

Comment: Thank you, but i'ld prefer to use pure js and not jquery. Can i get a solution i vanilla pls?